# How to fill a region with half-transparent color in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Many papers on image segmentation provide examples where each segment is covered with half-transparent color mask:

[image]

If I have an image and a mask, can I achieve the same result in Matplotlib?

**EDIT:**

The mask in my case is defined as an array with the same width and height as an image filled with numbers from 0 to (num_segments+1), where 0 means "don't apply any color" and other numbers mean "cover this pixel with some distinct color". Yet, if another representation of a mask is more suitable, I can try to convert to it.

Here are a couple of complications that I found in this task so that it doesn't sound that trivial:

1. Colored regions are not regular shapes like lines, squares or circles so functions like `plot(..., 'o')`, `fill()` or `fill_between()` don't work here. They are not even [contours](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) (or at least I don't see how to apply them here).
2. Modifying alpha channel isn't the most popular thing in plots, so is rarely mentioned in Matplotlib's docs.

Comment: I would appreciate if downvoters explain their decision and point out how to improve the question. After several hours of googling and experimenting without any result, it's pretty frustrating to see that the question is not only unanswered on SO (the answer below doesn't cover my needs), but also downvoted twice without any comments. For reference, there's at least 2 differences with normal graphs in Matplotlib: 1) regions to plot over an image don't have a regular shape like square or circle, but rather irregular filled contours; 2) there's also alpha channel that is rarely mentioned in docs

Comment: Concerning downvotes: I guess they were made before you edited the question to include some crucial details which somehow turned the question from a "is it possible to do ... using ...?"-type question to a real world problem. When I answered the question I did not have those details and I'm sure I would have provided an even more helpful answer if I had. Howevr, I suppose the answer still covers your needs (as you have accepted it). If it doesn't, feel free to ask further details.

Comment: Your answer provided all the pieces, connecting them wasn't that hard :) The reason I asked "is it possible" question is that I had 5 or 6 different directions to start with, and listing them all could make the question more confusing and clarifying (posted question is my 3rd version, actually). I expected to see some comments helping to figure our the details, or general recommendations on how to handle such cases, or some related example (as you provided) that I could use to clarify the question and dig into my use case. But maybe this is just not how things are done on SO now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can surely be done. The implementation would depend on how your mask looks like.

Here is an example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = plt.imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qe6z.png")

ar= np.zeros((image.shape[0],image.shape[1]) )
ar[100:300,50:150] = np.ones((200,100))
ar[:,322:] = np.zeros((image.shape[0],image.shape[1]-322) )*np.nan

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(image)
ax.imshow(ar, alpha=0.5, cmap="RdBu")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: After closer inspection, I see that your question actually does cover my needs. For future reference, here are the most important points for me: 1) to draw an irregular region `imshow()` may be used; 2) `imshow()` directly accepts `alpha` parameter; 3) (the most important) `np.nan` may be used to completely avoid drawing at specified pixels (as opposed to `np.zeros()` that would result in black color, or using `alpha=0` that would affect all regions). Thanks for valuable tips!